# std::unique_lock move semantic

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Please help me check if my understanding of `std::unique_lock` move semantic is correct.
Let's say I have a function `myFunc` which needs to acquire a mutex at the beginning of its execution.
This function is called from different functions, some of them e.g. `myWrapper1` hold the same mutex before `myFunc` call.
Sometimes I need this lock not be released when `myFunc`'s scope exits.

```
typedef std::unique_lock<std::mutex> MyLock;
class Example2
{
    std::mutex m_data_mutex;

    MyLock&& myFunc(MyLock&& lk)
    {
        bool was_lock = lk.owns_lock();
        if( !was_lock ) lk.lock();

        std::cout << "myFunc" << std::endl;

        if( !was_lock ) lk.unlock();
        return std::move(lk);
    }

    void myWrapper1()
    {
        MyLock lk(m_data_mutex);
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
        lk = myFunc(std::move(lk));
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    }

    void myWrapper2()
    {
        MyLock lk(m_data_mutex);
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
        lk.unlock();
        lk = myFunc(std::move(lk));
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
        lk.lock();
        std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

So the questions are:

1. for `myWrapper1` there's a guarantee that `MyLock` will be released only at the end of `myWrapper1` scope, isn't it?
2. Do I use a correct idiom for this problem?

Comment: 1. yes, 2. no. You technically just assign lk to itself that is pointless.

Comment: @ÖöTiib That is incorrect - the lock is _moved_, twice. Ownership of the lock changes over these function calls.

Comment: @osuka_ it is illusion that std::move moves. The std::move just takes rvalue reference to object. Since the reference is also returned back from myFunc no change of ownership ever occurs.

Comment: @ÖöTiib ah, you're correct - I suppose `operator=` should handle `obj = obj` just fine, though that serves no point. I'm more concerned here about the code smell - just what is this meant to accomplish? I can't think of a legitimate use for this idiom.

Comment: @ÖöTiib If I've understood you correct, `std::move(lk)` doesn't "destroy" lk when passing it to `myFunc` as param, so I don't need to  "move it back". So `myFunc` declaration can look like this: `void myFunc(MyLock&& lk)`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk Better void myFunc(MyLock& lk) and remove std::move when passing lk it only confuses people.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Well, it compiles, but `std::unique_lock` doesn't have copy constructor: `unique_lock(unique_lock const&); // = delete;
    unique_lock& operator=(unique_lock const&); // = delete; `, so is a "move" implicit in such case?

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk nothing happens on either of these examples because a second lock is never instantiated. There is no call to a constructor; ownership would only transfer if the lock was passed "by copy" (i.e., not by reference) - then, the move c'tor would be invoked.

Comment: @osuka_ Thanks, I've got it!

Comment: If `myFunc` isn't expected to keep ownership of your lock, I would just have it take a `MyLock&` and forget about rvalue references for this application.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks, I've got it!

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::recursive_mutex` and forget about checking whether the lock is owned..

Comment: Example: https://ideone.com/ZNfzWI

Comment: @Brandon Thanks, this looks like a solution to the problem! However, I plan to add a one more mutex, and don't want to statically analyse a deadlock if MyLock(mutex1) was acquired before the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some reason why you can't do something like this instead? IMO, it's a lot more clean than moving locks around from owner to owner.

```
std::mutex my_lock;

void myFunc_locked() {
    ...do something that requires my_lock to be locked...
}

void myFunc() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(my_lock);
    myFunc_locked();
}

void myWrapper1() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(my_lock);
    ...do something else that requires my_lock to be locked...
    myFunc_locked();
}

void myWrapper2() {
    ...
    myFunc();
}
```

---

Or, do as @Nevin suggested. Maybe cleaner still:

```
std::mutex my_lock;

void myFunc(std::lock_guard<std::mutex>> const& guard) {
    ...do something that requires my_lock to be locked...
}

void myFunc() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(my_lock);
    myFunc(guard);
}

void myWrapper1() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(my_lock);
    ...do something else that requires my_lock to be locked...
    myFunc(guard);
}

void myWrapper2() {
    ...
    myFunc();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good approach. However sometimes it's hard to see if the same lock wasn't acquired before the call to `myFunc`, and deadlock can happen. Actually, I started exploring this question after I catched a deadlock.